# Obfuscate or Crypt C/C++ Code

Tags: c++, obfuscation, crypt

I need a utility/tool or another way to obfuscate or crypt code block in C/C++ source code, like:

```
int myfunc()
{
   BEGIN_CRYPT
   return 0;
   END_CRYPT
}

int main()
{
    BEGIN_CRYPT   
        printf( "This part is crypted\n" );
    END_CRYPT

    printf( "This part isn't crypted\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone know a utility/tool for this?

Thank you
Daniele

Comment: This has nothing to do with encryption. Is it the referenced strings (here "this part is encrypted") you want to obfuscate? or generally obfuscate the generated code?

Comment: I need crypt the all source code between BEGIN_CRYPT and END_CRYPT.  In others words, the code is decrypted in memory

Comment: To encrypt something you need a key. But to decrypt you will also need a key. It needs to be decrypted at runtime, so someone debugging your application will be able to get the key and decrypt it himself. Its not possible to keep code that needs to be run in memory secret to anyone who has access to the memory. Maybe try to explain what you are trying to keep secret, so maybe there is a solution for it. Obfuscation will not keep it secret, if someone really wants to figure it out.

Comment: I need "crypt" the code.  It's only to difficult look strings and codes, not to create a very-ultra-powerfull protection.  Maybe a pre-build tool to convert the code between macros to a virtualized or crypt code is welcome.  Thank you

Comment: You really should learn the proper terminology. You don't want to encrypt your *source* code. You want to encrypt the *resulting* executable pieces that the code corresponds to.

Comment: Sorry, my english isn't good and I don't explain correctly. Nik Bougalis, do you know any utility/tool to help me?  thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know a long time has passed since the original question but I had the same needs to obfuscate part of the source code so no other developers could figure them out.

as a rule of thumb, all methods of obfuscation are reversible if anyone spends enough time to restore the source to the original. this applies to other language obfuscations like javascript.

however if you still need to just "Obfuscate" your source code, Stunnix seems the only commercial product capable of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

- If the portion is encrypted, only the person with the private key will be able to read it and compile it.
- If the portion is obfuscated, the dedicated engineer will be able to figure it out.
- If you really don't want to give out your secrets, distribute myfunc() as a library object (as  opposed to source code) and distribute it.

Having said that, I don't really know of any C++ obfuscator (maybe if you search for JavaScript obfuscator projects you can find links to other obfuscators which they may have used as inspiration)

Comment: I found a tool:  PELock:  hxxp://www.pelock.com/download.php?f=pelock.zip  inside the .zip \examples\CodeEncryption\C\console have exactly I need, but they dont work for me.   Maybe there is anothers tools available